# order the sequence of .css and .animate scripts

Tags: jquery, css

I have a script that moves a div right and changes the width - but I'm having trouble control the order that the effects trigger.

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#access').click(function(){                    
        $('#active').animate({right:"6px"}, 400);
        $('#active').css({width:"60px"});
    });
});
```

What happens now is that #active changes width, then moves to the right.  I'd like the width change to happen during the animation (ideally) or at least after it has finished moving right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('#active').animate({right: "6px", width: "60px"}, 400);
```

To change width after moving right:

```
$('#active').animate({right: "6px"}, 400, function(){
  $('#active').css({width: "60px"}); // without animation
  // or
  $('#active').animate({width: "60px"}); // with animation
});
```

Comment: Ahh, using a callback, that makes sense.  Cool, both of these work, thanks